# Promise never settles - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I've made the following loop, where I loop an Array; and then doing a quick GET request for each of them.

I made the loop work and the data is logged correctly. However the "loop" never finishes, and therefore not reaching `().then => {}`

```
Promise.all(
    arr.map((key,item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var costmicro = 0;
        request.post({
            url: 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v8/customers/'+arr[item]+'/googleAds:searchStream',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            json: {
                "query": "SELECT metrics.cost_micros FROM campaign WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS",
            }
            }, function (errAdsCampaign, httpResponseAdsCampaign, bodyAdsCampaign) {
                if (!errAdsCampaign) {
                for (ii in bodyAdsCampaign[0].results) {
                    costmicro = costmicro+parseInt(bodyAdsCampaign[0].results[ii].metrics['costMicros']);
                    var arrlength = bodyAdsCampaign[0].results.length-1;
                        if (ii == arrlength) {
                            objectArray.push({name: arr[item], cost: costmicro / 1000000});
                            resolve(objectArray);
                        }
                }
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
    })
).then(()=>{
    console.log('done');
    console.log(objectArray)
}).catch(() => {
    console.error;
});
```

UPDATE
Replaced the catch() function. Like so; sadly it never returns an error, and never finished

```
}).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You are only calling `resolve(…)` if your `for` loop finds any results, but it's not guaranteed to do that. Better always immediately `resolve()` with the http response, then do the processing in a `.then()` callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your function inside the loop, you need to account for all possible exit paths and call either `resolve()` or `reject()`. One such exit path that is not handled is if `bodyAdsCampaign[0].results` is an empty array or undefined. In this case, the function will finish running without calling `resolve()` or `reject()`.

You can also add a call to `reject()` at the end of your `function (errAdsCampaign, httpResponseAdsCampaign, bodyAdsCampaign)` callback function to catch all scenarios which aren't handled within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the loop likely threw an error and it skipped the `.then()` clause and went to the `.catch()` clause. You can replace the `.catch()` clause with the code below to see what error was encountered.

```js
}).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Tried adding the new catch() code, yet it dosen't throw an error. Just never seems to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The library `request` has been deprecated. Ref. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Instead, I would suggest using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

```js
(async function run() {
  try {
    const objectArray = await Promise.all(
      arr.map(async (key, item) => {
        const res = await axios.post(
          "https://googleads.googleapis.com/v8/customers/" +
            arr[item] +
            "/googleAds:searchStream",
          {
            json: {
              query:
                "SELECT metrics.cost_micros FROM campaign WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS",
            },
          },
          {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',,
            },
          }
        );

        const costmicro = res.data.bodyAdsCampaign.results.reduce((acc, cur) => {
          acc += cur.metrics["costMicros"];
          return acc;
        }, 0);

        return { name: arr[item], cost: costmicro / 1000000 };
      })
    );

    console.log(objectArray);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```